# How do I get help messages to appear for my Powershell script parameters?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell script (`setup.ps1`), that we use as the entry point for our development environment setup scripts.  It takes a parameter:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,HelpMessage="The targets to run.")]
    [Alias("t")]
    [string[]]
    $Targets = "Help"
)
```

When I run

```
PS > get-help .\setup.ps1 -detailed
```

in the parameters section, my help message doesn't appear:

```
PARAMETERS
    -Targets <String[]>
```

What do I need to do to get my parameter help messages to display?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You put a certain style of comment at the top of the file that can be decoded by the PowerShell help system.  Here's an example:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    .
.DESCRIPTION
    .
.PARAMETER Path
    The path to the .
.PARAMETER LiteralPath
    Specifies a path to one or more locations. Unlike Path, the value of 
    LiteralPath is used exactly as it is typed. No characters are interpreted 
    as wildcards. If the path includes escape characters, enclose it in single
    quotation marks. Single quotation marks tell Windows PowerShell not to 
    interpret any characters as escape sequences.
.EXAMPLE
    C:\PS> 
    <Description of example>
.NOTES
    Author: Keith Hill
    Date:   June 28, 2010    
#>
function AdvFuncToProcessPaths
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Path")]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ParameterSetName="Path", 
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true, 
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   HelpMessage="Path to ...")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]
        $Path,

        [Alias("PSPath")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ParameterSetName="LiteralPath", 
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   HelpMessage="Path to ...")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]
        $LiteralPath
    )
    ...
```

For more info see the help topic - `man about_comment_based_help`.

Comment: I see.  So the `HelpMessage` property on the `Parameter` attribute is actually *ignored* by the PowerShell help system.  That's not confusing. :/

Comment: Yeah it is a bit confusing. That HelpMessage attribute on the parmeter is *not* ignored though. It is used when you invoke the command without specifying a mandatory parameter. At that point you are prompted to enter a value for that parameter. If you specify a `HelpMessage`, that text is displayed as part of that prompt.

Comment: But only if you enter "!?" when PowerShell is prompting for a value to that mandatory parameter.  This is little known.

Comment: @JasonMArcher - ISE shows the help message without additional effort.

Comment: Apparently, this only works if your params are declared using that param-block style above (which, to me is extremely over verbose and cumbersome).  I have functions written like regular programming functions, and `get-help` doesn't work with a document block as above.

Answer (score 31):

Apparently if you have a help header defined, you can just use a remark (#) behind the parameter (in this example: ***#The targets to run.***):

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    .
.DESCRIPTION
    .
.PARAMETER Path
    The path to the .
.PARAMETER LiteralPath
    Specifies a path to one or more locations. Unlike Path, the value of 
    LiteralPath is used exactly as it is typed. No characters are interpreted 
    as wildcards. If the path includes escape characters, enclose it in single
    quotation marks. Single quotation marks tell Windows PowerShell not to 
    interpret any characters as escape sequences.
#>

Param(
    [String]$Targets = "Help"   #The targets to run.
)
```

Results in:

```
PS C:\> Get-help .\Setup.ps1 -Detailed

NAME
    C:\Setup.ps1

SYNOPSIS
    .


SYNTAX
    C:\Setup.ps1 [[-Targets] <String>] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    .


PARAMETERS
    -Targets <String>
        The targets to run.
```

Comment: Alternatively you can put the comment on the line before the parameter, which might work better for longer descriptions and longer param names.

Comment: Why don't you put the Target Parameter in the section where you describe parameters, e. g. before or after `.PARAMETER Path`

Comment: In PS3 you get a different (better) result for `get-help -detailed`: All the Parameters and the description in `.PARAMETER`  are shown.

Answer (score 14):

one **just needs the `<# .SYNOPSIS #>` part on top** of the file to make it work and you can **comment your params nicely inline**:

```
<# .SYNOPSIS #>
param(
   [String]$foo   ## my 1st cool param
  ,[Switch]$bar  ## my 2nd crazy switch
)
...
```

(checked with `PS 5.1.14409.1018`)

Comment: Weird, if I used the "full" options above, it gave me less output then with just this one line... I like it!

Comment: This is rather confusing syntax with comma starting new line, but putting ## clue on a separate line is possible.