# Get-Help will not return only returns <CommonParameters>

Tags: powershell-3.0

(Hi)

(PS V. 3)

I'm pulling my hair out here. I have the following code:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Some Synopsis
.DESCRIPTION
    A Description
.PARAMETER MyParameter
    The script requires the MyParameter parameter to be set to Red, Green or Blue.
.EXAMPLE
    C:\PS>.\example.ps1 red
.EXAMPLE
    C:\PS>.\example.ps1 green
.EXAMPLE
    C:\PS> .\example.ps1 blue
.INPUTS
    This script take to piped input.
.OUTPUTS
    The script will return a colour to the given answer.
#>


Function Select-Colour
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
           [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0,HelpMessage="Please enter either red, green or blue for MyParameter.")]
           [ValidateSet('Easy','Medium','Hard')]
           [System.String]
           $MyParameter
          ) 

End snip
```

However, wherever I place the help tag, inside the function, at the top or bottom of the script, it will only list common parameters. There are two blank lines between the #> and Function Select-Colour.

The only way I can get it to work is by placing the Param block outside the Select-Colour function, however, this breaks the Try / Catch block (omitted).

How do I get Get-Help .\example.ps1 -full to show the Parameter MyParameter?

All other tags show fine, except Example, where there are 5 blank lines inserted from somewhere. If that's a clue.

Apparently it's easy!

Many thanks

W.

Comment: I've seen several examples just like this so I'm sure it should work. One example (on here) doesn't leave any space blank lines between the end script block and function, stating that's how it works. For me all I get in Get-Help is the script's file name.

Comment: Anyone? Not just me then?

Comment: @keith hill, I wonder if you would be able to comment. I have seen your reply to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237723/how-do-i-get-help-messages-to-appear-for-my-powershell-script-parameters where you show no blank lines. I've tried your example and I get exactly the same results. Either only the script name or with two blank lines, only <CommonParameters>. Thanks