# Using Mandatory Parameters

Tags: powershell

Im developing this user script and would like some help with it. I just want to know how to set mandatory parameters or something similar to the below variables so that i can make the user enters some info instead of having a null value on a variable. Any help or advice would be appreciated Thanks in advance.

```
$username = Read-host "Enter username"
$fname = Read-Host "ENTER First Name"
$lname = Read-Host "ENTER Last Name"
$Des   = Read-Host "ENTER Description (Work Area)"
$Title = Read-Host "ENTER Job Title"`enter code here`
```

Comment: Now, do you mean that the user must enter the parameters as arguments when they run the script, or are you wanting to prompt the user for this, and not accept null responses?

Comment: Yes im wanting to prompt the user for info and not accept null responses. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237723/how-do-i-get-help-messages-to-appear-for-my-powershell-script-parameters

Comment: @jrussellaz Not really, he just worded his title poorly. He doesn't want mandatory parameters, he just wants to prompt the user for input and not accept null responses.

Comment: Just looking for clarification so I can tag duplicates more effectively in the future. Not a duplicate but the answer is the same? Check out this comment from @keith-hill: "Yeah it is a bit confusing. That HelpMessage attribute on the parmeter is not ignored though. It is used when you invoke the command without specifying a mandatory parameter. At that point you are prompted to enter a value for that parameter. If you specify a HelpMessage, that text is displayed as part of that prompt."

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter attributes:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="Enter username")]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    $username,

    ...
)
```

Note that the console doesn't use the HelpMessage (by default) as a prompt for mandatory parameters but ISE does.  There is also the `[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]` attribute that would disallow empty strings as well.

BTW the advantage of using parameter attributes is if the function/script is called with arguments there is no prompting.  If a parameter is not specified then PowerShell will prompt for the argument for you.  In general, I like for PowerShell to do as much of the work as I can get it to.  :-)

Comment: Check the comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237723/how-do-i-get-help-messages-to-appear-for-my-powershell-script-parameters from @keith-hill: "Yeah it is a bit confusing. That HelpMessage attribute on the parmeter is not ignored though. It is used when you invoke the command without specifying a mandatory parameter. At that point you are prompted to enter a value for that parameter. If you specify a HelpMessage, that text is displayed as part of that prompt."

Comment: I think the discoverability of `!?` is so low that HelpMessage is `effectively` not used by the console.  It seems odd that ISE and console would deviate on this.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a function that checks for $null or whitespace only strings, and re-prompts the user for the info. Something like:

```
function get-NonNullString{
Param([string]$Prompt=(throw "You must provide text as a prompt"))
    $Output = Read-Host $prompt
    While([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Output)){
        write-host "`nYou must enter a response!`n" -ForegroundColor Red
        $Output = Read-Host $prompt
    }
}
```

Then you would call it like:

```
$username = Get-NonNullString "Enter username"
$fname = Get-NonNullString "ENTER First Name"
$lname = Get-NonNullString "ENTER Last Name"
$Des   = Get-NonNullString "ENTER Description (Work Area)"
$Title = Get-NonNullString "ENTER Job Title"
```

Comment: While I try to write-host "$username" and write-host $username it has no value.