# PowerShell "Get-Help -ShowWindow" won't show all help sections

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

even though they are selected in settings

[image]

in particular, the parameters are missing. The same happens in the console. Win 10 Pre, PowerShell v5 respectively

Any ideas?

thanx

PS
that's what I'm missing, it should show up in the window just like when using the -full switch

```
PARAMETERS
-Param1 <Object>
    Param1 help description

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    1
    Default value                
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue, ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false

-Param2 <Int32>
    Param2 help description

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                0
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false

-Param3 <String>
    Param3 help description

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false

-WhatIf [<SwitchParameter>]

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false

-Confirm [<SwitchParameter>]

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false

<CommonParameters>
    This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
    ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
    OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable. For more information, see 
    about_CommonParameters (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216).
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get help messages to appear for my Powershell script parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237723/how-do-i-get-help-messages-to-appear-for-my-powershell-script-parameters)

Comment: The help text for parameters should go to the main help section, designated by the parameter name. Those comments at `param()` block do not get parsed by `Get-Help`.

Comment: I don't' think they use that approach for quite some time now. Even "Get-Help Get-Help -ShowWindow" won't show the parameters section... that is it's an issue with any cmdlet

Comment: @Vesper that's an entirely different issue. itd be nice if you didn't randomly suggest dupes ;)

Comment: Then it's weird. Probably Powershell-5 specific, just tried that on PS4/Win7 and got full text with parameters.

Comment: yeah, I know it should work fine. I'm wondering if it might be related to some settings stored in the "cloud" and never properly updated... doubt it is a quirk of powershell v5 itself, at least it shouldn't be at this point

nope, not "cloud" related. just tried with a "local" account

Comment: The problem appears to happen when I include CmdLetBinding on the function. While this is active help context doesn't work correctly, as of powershell v7.3.4. Microsoft will likely depreciate PowerShell long before this gets fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known bug.

I know it doesn't help you very much but at least you don't have to look for a solution since Microsoft is on it.

You can look for updated information here: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1549114/ps5-get-help-showwindow-doesnt-display-help-on-parameters

Comment: Yeah they're hot on the trail of fixing that bug. It's 2023 and it's still an issue. Thanks Microsoft