# How do I configure help and usage statements in a powershell script?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have the powershell script `foo.ps1`:

```
<# test foo.ps1 #>
param(
  [CmdletBinding()]
  [Switch]$foo,
  [Switch]$bar
)
```

Which has a few automatic parameters like `-Debug` and `-Verbose` in addition to the custom parameters `-foo` and `-bar`.

I should be able to see all of these parameters when I do something like `.\foo.ps1 --help`, or I should be able to configure that somehow.

---

What is the core way to do this in powershell?

Comment: i think this may answer question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237723/how-do-i-get-help-messages-to-appear-for-my-powershell-script-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Command` will return you the full list of parameters, including common parameters:

```
$myScript = Get-Command .\foo.ps1

# this is a dictionary containing all the parameters
$myScript.Parameters 

# we can index into it like any other dictionary to inspect the parameter metadata for a given parameter
$myScript.Parameters['bar']
```

---

With regards to `Get-Help`, that part is already taken care of for you - when you do `Get-Help .\foo.ps1` or `.\foo -?` after adding a CmdletBinding, PowerShell will automatically add `[<CommonParameters>]` to the command syntax string to indicate that common parameters are accepted:

Without `[CmdletBinding()]` decorator:

```
f [-foo] [-bar]
```

With `[CmdletBinding()]` decorator (or any parameter attribute decorators) specified:

```
f [-foo] [-bar]  [<CommonParameters>]
```

If you want richer help content displayed, [then you'll need to provide it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-7.3) :)

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76877740/45375):

- The conceptual [about_Command_Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax) help topic discusses PowerShell's *syntax diagrams*, which is PowerShell's notation for documenting a command's supported parameters, their data types, whether they are mandatory, and whether they can be bound positionally.
- The *common parameters* (such as `-Debug` and `-Verbose`) that are *implicitly* supported by compiled cmdlets and [*advanced*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) functions and scripts<sup>[1]</sup> are documented in the conceptual [about_CommonParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters) help topic.
- Common parameters are never shown *individually* in syntax diagrams, only with the collective placeholder `[<CommonParameters>]`, as shown in Mathias' answer.
- Due to a *bug*, present up to at least PowerShell (Core) 7.3.6, this placeholder is mistakenly also shown for *non*-advanced functions and scripts, *if* they happen to define *comment-based help*, as documented in the conceptual [about_Comment_Based_Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comment_Based_Help) help topic; here's a minimal example:

  ```
  # !! Output mistakenly suggests that Get-Foo supports common parameters.
  function Get-Foo { <#.SYNOPSIS #> }; Get-Foo -?
  ```

  - The relevant bug report is [GitHub issue #17312](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17312)
- Syntax diagrams can be shown with parameter `-?` (for cmdlets and *advanced* functions and scripts as well as functions and scripts with comment-based help, even if non-advanced), [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) (for any command except external programs), and, in isolation, with [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) `-Syntax`, which takes its information directly from the command's definition, whereas `Get-Help` may take its information from an external help file, if present; since a help file may get out of sync with the actual implementation, `Get-Command -Syntax` is a more reliable source.
- That syntax diagrams never show enumerate the common parameters individually is somewhat unfortunate:

  - The following two common parameters aren't supported by *all* cmdlets / advanced functions and scripts, as they require *opt-in* via the `ShouldProcess` property of the [`[CmdletBinding()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdletbindingattribute) attribute:

    - [`-WhatIf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-whatif)
    - [`-Confirm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-confirm)
    - As a rule of thumb, only cmdlets that have *side effects*, notably potentially *destructive* ones support these parameters, such as `Remove-Item`
    - *Tab-completion* can tell you for a given command whether these common parameters are supported or not.
  - As Mathias notes, `(Get-Command ...).Parameters` allows you to enumerate *all* parameters of a given command, *including* common ones.

    - To get only the list of *non-common*, i.e. *command-specific* parameters, you can use the following, using `Remove-Item` as an example command:

      ```
      (
        [System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData] (Get-Command Remove-Item)
      ).Parameters
      ```
    - To get the *complete list of common parameters* (note that these properties are currently *undocumented*, and `OptionalCommonParameters` includes an *obsolete* entry, `-UseTransaction`):

      ```
       (
         [System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet]::CommonParameters +
         [System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet]::OptionalCommonParameters 
       )
      ```
    - To test whether a given cmdlet supports `-WhatIf` and `-Confirm`:

      ```
       (Get-Command Remove-Item).Parameters.Keys -contains 'WhatIf'
      ```

---

<sup>[1] In short: It is the use of a `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute *and/or* of at least one parameter-individual `[Parameter()]` attribute that makes a function or script and advanced one.</sup>